# What should we do about questions that involve bugs with 3rd party tools?

Tags: discussion

**Potential Culprits**

[Xbox Controller Not Connecting in Monogame Project](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63532/xbox-controller-not-connecting-in-monogame-project)
[Can't load vector font in Nuclex Framework](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35496/cant-load-vector-font-in-nuclex-framework)
[SpriteFont not found in Nuclex Framework](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67246/spritefont-not-found-in-nuclex-framework)

Do we answer these? Do we close them? It doesn't seem to make sense to answer questions for bugs unless we're encouraged to post "work arounds". It seems the workarounds would be far too localized and short lived to be worth much. They're also not worth much in terms of historical significance.

Comment: I generally consider most of these to fall into the same bucket as "debug my code for me," they are essentially "solve my problem for me," in many cases and you usually aren't given the information you actually need. But these should still be looked at on a case-by-case basis I think.

Answer (score 1):

I see the excuse too localized or too short lived far too often on this site. This isn't a theoretical game development Q&A. That would warrant questions that should at least be relevant for a few years. Questions regarding specific frameworks and problems with frameworks are on-topic on this site. So why not questions regarding bugs in frameworks?

Another argument is that it is often not known in advance that it is a bug by the user who posted the question or even by us.

This also raises another question, when is something too short-lived. Even bugs known by the developer can stay around for months or years, doesn't that discard all of the arguments against the validity of these questions?

Personally I think we should try to make our community more open, lately too many questions are being closed because the FAQ is interpreted too strictly (IMHO). Apply the FAQ as a general guideline.

Comment: I think framework bug questions ought to be permitted, for all the reasons you mentioned.  Shortlived-ness also is not a good close reason; that's what update edit are for.  But too localized is surely still a valid reason.  As Josh said, case-by-case is the way to judge.

Answer (score 1):

I found this relevant Venn diagram in the [help of Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  (Can we get this in our help, with "Programmers" crossed out in favor of "Game Developers"?)

[image]

Honestly, I think this criterion should be applied for every close reason.  If the question about a 3rd party framework is a common pitfall, or perhaps some frequent gotcha of implementing it, or even a known bug, that's a useful question.  If it's simply being used wrongly, close it.